# If Check box clicked then dependent fields should be mandatory or else normal

Tags: visualforce

there is a check box and it have related 4 fields, when the check box checked then the fields should be required fields or else the field show as normal fields, please find my sample code. provide me correct code.

```
public class SampleClass {
    public Customer__c quoteObj {get;set;}
    public boolean dispSectBool {get;set;}

    public SampleClass(ApexPages.StandardController controller) {
        dispSectBool = false;
    }
}
```

---

```
<apex:page standardController="Customer__c" extensions="SampleClass">
    <apex:form >
        <apex:inputField value="{!quoteObj.sample__c}"/>   
        <apex:actionSupport event="onclick" action="{!dispSect}" rerender="checkBx"/>
        <apex:outputpanel id="checkBx">
            <apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(if(dispSectBool==true, true, false))}" id="pgBlock">
                <apex:inputField value="{!quoteObj.additional_site_visits__c}" required="true"/>
            </apex:outputpanel>
        </apex:outputpanel>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by binding "required" to the Boolean field, and reRendering as necessary:

```
<apex:page standardController="Customer__c">
  <apex:form id="form">
  <apex:inputField value="{!Customer__c.sample__c}">   
    <!-- actionSupport should be a child of inputField -->
    <apex:actionSupport event="onchange" rerender="form"/>
  </apex:inputField>
<apex:inputField value="{!Customer__c.additional_site_visits__c}" required="{!Customer__c.sample__c}"/>
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```